# kafka import/export data in local system

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, bigdata

When i try to import/export data by using kafka. I ran a query

> bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties config/connect-file-sink.properties.

But i getting error

ERROR Failed to create job for config/connect-file-sink.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:89)
[2017-05-10 21:26:49,110] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:100)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.AlreadyExistsException: Connector local-file already exists
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:97)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.AlreadyExistsException: Connector local-file already exists
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:145)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:94).

Please help me out to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the same connector name for your two connectors you are trying to run in this worker

> Connector local-file already exists

Try changing the name property in one of you connector configuration files.